# Magento - Problem formatting price for indian rupee

Tags: magento

i modified following code to show indian rupee

```
public function formatPrecision($price, $precision,
$options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)

   {

       if (!isset($options['precision'])) {

           $options['precision'] = $precision;

       }

       if ($includeContainer) {

           return '<span class="price">' . ($addBrackets ? '[' :
'') . $this->formatTxt($price, $options) . ($addBrackets ? ']' : '') .
'</span>';

       }

       return $this->formatTxt($price, $options);

   }
```

everywhere on site its showing perfect but only in product
specification table it shows `<span class="price">200</span>`.

This happens only on live server not on staging and local

Please help

Comment: What is the exact question? What is the expected result?

Comment: why it returning html as text only in product specification?

Comment: Are you using any javascript or css for rupee symbol if yes are you not using skin url to include them??